# Numerical stability by solving with pivoting and without pivoting for lower triangular matrices where 1's at the diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

Assume that we are going to solve $Ax=b$ and $A$ is lower triangular and $1$ at the diagonal. It's sounds perfect! Easy to solve.

That can be solved by using
$$x_{k+1} = b_k + \sum_{i=0}^kA(k,i)x_i$$

Where $x_0 = b_0$

But then I read this report about Observer Kalman Filter identification at page 324.
http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/SystemID/References/Juang+Phan+etal-JGCD-1993.pdf

[image]

So if $A$ is lower triangular, with $1$ at the diagonal. It still better to solve with QR or LUP or SVD? Even if I can solve it with back substitution?

Here is an example. The red line should fade to zeros, but it doesn't.

[image]

Formula that cause this trouble:

$$Y_k^o = -Y^{(2)}_k + \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1}Y^{(2)}_i Y^o_{k-i-1}$$

Comment: I am very skeptical about the author's claim. It is a shame that they do not specify exactly what they mean by "recursive back-substitution". I can imagine that if you have a block triangular matrix and explicitly invert the diagonal blocks, then you are asking for trouble. I would go ahead a do substitution either recursively or using a partitioned algorithm such as DTRSM from LAPACK.

Comment: @CarlChristian Hej! Som inverting A is a bad idea? In this case $x$ matrix too.

Comment: @CarlChristian Look at the equation 20. Better to do inverse?

Comment: @CarlChristian I have updated my question.

Comment: You **never** need to invert if you're solving a linear system. SInce you have a *unit* **lower** triangular matrix, you use "forward elimination" ("backsubstitution" is intended for **upper** triangular matrices). Your first formula is ***not*** how to do forward elimination; see e.g. [Golub and Van Loan](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=mlOa7wPX6OYC&pg=PA88) on how to do this.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Thank you. I have solved the system as you see in the question. Found a way...but I don't like it because it very unstable some times. Depending what data I'm using.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician I have posted the forward elimination formula.

Comment: Like I said, if you are using the first formula you mentioned, then that **isn't** the correct formula for forward elimination. That being said, if you really do want to try something with pivoting, try LU decomposition first. Perhaps also consider putting in a way to monitor the condition number of the matrices you are dealing with. (There should be functions to find the condition number in most computing environments, so look those up.)

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Yes. I have written lots of decompositions in pure C code such as QR with householder. But in this case, I not know how solve when my initial matrix is already lower triangular. The best way if I got started with a non-triangular matrix.

Comment: "I not know how solve when my initial matrix is already lower triangular." - when you're feeding it into something like LU or QR, you are effectively **ignoring** the fact that it's triangular, and you are just treating it like any other matrix. The price to pay for this is that the process is now $O(n^3)$ in effort, but such is the desire for stability...

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician So you mean that I should solve $A$ with e.g LUP-factorization (pivoting), even if $A$ is a lower triangular with 1's at the diagonal?

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Notice that $Y^o_k$ is a matrix.

Comment: OK, some of what I said seems to have been lost in the confusion, so: try doing your Kalman filter computations again, but this time, hook up a function for computing the condition number of your triangular matrices as you go along. Monitor the condition number. If its logarithm is larger than the number of digits you're willing to lose in your computations, we surely have a problem.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician I tried to find the condition number and it was about 200-400 depedning on what norm I had.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician But I will try again to create my lower triangular matrices again and solve with with LUP. Giving you a reply later.

Comment: The norm choice isn't much of a concern, all you need for condition numbers is an idea of how big it is (hence my mention of the logarithm). So: the matrices are not so ill-conditioned; it's just that you need to try hooking up a full LU decomposition with pivoting instead of just solving a triangular system. If that's still not going right, then I suspect the linear system solutions are in fact not the source of your problems.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Ok. Thank you. I think that LUP will handle this lower triangular beast :)

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Solved it now. I only needed to change the indexing in the $V$ matrix at equation $8$ to $p = N/2 - q - m -1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nonsingular lower triangular linear system $Lx = b$ can be solved using forward substitution. If $L$ is an $n$ by $n$ nonsingular lower triangular matrix, then the computed solution $\hat{x}$ satisfies a perturbed linear system $$(L + \Delta L)\hat{x} = f,$$ where $$|\Delta L| \leq \gamma_{n} |L|, \quad \gamma_n = \frac{nu}{1-nu}$$
and $u$ is the unit roundoff. This inequality should be understood in the componentwise sense, i.e., $$|(\Delta L)_{ij}| \leq \gamma_{n} |L_{ij}|.$$ We see that forward substitution produces the exact solution of a problem which is very close to our problem. Formally, we say that forward substitution is componentwise relative backward stable. This is as good as it gets in numerical analysis. In particular, there is no reason to deploy solvers which are based on $QR$ or $LU$ factorization of $L$.

There is no guarantee that the computed solution $\hat{x}$ is close to the true solution $x$, unless the appropriate condition number is small. In this context, Skeel's condition numbers $\text{cond}(L,x)$ and $\text{cond}(L)$ are suitable. By definition, we have $$\text{cond}(L,x) = \frac{\| |L| |L^{-1}| |x| \|_\infty}{\|x\|_\infty}$$ and $$\text{cond}(L) = \| |L| |L^{-1}| \|_\infty.$$ In terms of Skeel's condition numbers, we have the forward relative error bound 
$$ \frac{\|x - \hat{x}\|_\infty}{\|x\|_\infty} \leq \frac{\text{cond}(L,x) \gamma_n}{1 - \text{cond}(L)\gamma_n}.$$
This bound can be significantly better than the standard error bound which involves the classical condition number $\kappa_\infty(L) = \|L\|_\infty \|L^{-1}\|_\infty$.

The results quoted here can all be found in Higham's book "Accuracy and stability of Numerical Algorithms". Free versions of the 2nd edition are readily available online. The central chapters are 3, 7 and 8.

---

I have not read the paper cited in the original question. I suspect that the problem which you experience is not in your linear solver. In your case, I would test my linear solver by constructing linear systems with known solutions and verifying that the computed solutions satisfies the bound given above. This is done as follows. Choose $x$. Compute $f = Lx$ and feed $L$ and $f$ to your solver to produce $\hat{x} \approx x$.

Comment: Hi Carl Christian! I have created a new question that you might like. It's also a claim without any explanation. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3639028/computing-matrices-from-data-or-computing-matrices-by-using-other-matrices-nume